# How replace var to let "closure callback"

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, closures

In my book [MEAN 2nd Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0134655532)

The examples are all old. Help how to bring this code to the ES6 standard
If I change var to let then the code doesn't work.
I understand why, but how to write correctly

```
function logCar(logMsg, callback){
    process.nextTick(function() {
        callback(logMsg);
    });
}

const cars = ["Ferrari", "Porsche", "Bugatti"];

for (const idx of cars){
    var message = "Saw a " + cars[idx];
    logCar(message, ()=>console.log("Normal Callback: " + message));
}


for (const idx in cars){
    var message = "Saw a " + cars[idx];
    ((msg)=>{
        logCar(msg, ()=> console.log("Closure Callback: " + msg));
    })(message);
}
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work". If you're talking about value of `message` variable becoming `undefined` inside 'normal callback', that's actually a feature.

Comment: If you replace `var` by `let` (or better yet, `const`) in the first loop, it becomes equivalent to the "closure callback" example of the second loop. That's the whole point of block-scoped variables.

Comment: Btw, does the book already use `const` for `cars` and `idx`? That's really weird.

Answer (score 0):

This code is really weird; too much noise hiding the not-so-complicated subject.

The key issue is that the first loop is essentially broken: line...

```
for (const idx of cars)
```

... iterates not over indexes, but over *values* of `cars` array instead. Hence this...

```
var message = "Saw a " + cars[idx];
```

... never assigns 'Ferrari', 'Porsche' etc. to that variable: instead it uses those strings as indexes and ends up with `undefined`.

And that's what you see when you localize `message`, either with `let` or `const`. That also has nothing to with functions themselves, they will be scoped over correct let/const-ed `message`. So this...

```
for (const idx in cars) { // note that `in`
    const message = "Saw a " + cars[idx];
    logCar(message, ()=>console.log("Normal Callback: " + message));
}
```

... actually logs different values just fine.

The original code still 'works' though, because `message` name is actually shared between those blocks: `var` statement in the second loop is ignored and treated as assignment expression. So its value gets overwritten by the second loop (which uses `in cars`, not `of cars`) in time when `logCar` starts using the callbacks.

---

Still, that's only the beginning. While `logCar` is expected to invoke its callback with a single argument - the value of its first param - all the callbacks used in this code just ignore that. So the only difference is that the 2nd loop callback is "scoped" over the value while the 1st one uses the global var.

And yes, seeing `process.nextTick` is another strangeness, blast from the past. Not only this makes the code Node-only for no good reason (the effects are the same for both worlds; it's JavaScript, darnit!), but also its usage [is discouraged](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/#process-nexttick-vs-setimmediate) because, well, it's not really *nextTick*.

Answer (score 0):

since `var` is function scoped and `let` is blocked scoped you'll need to define `message` in the right scope as it was defined with the `var` and here it's in the global scope (which is not really a good practice) so this code should be how you'll write it:

```
function logCar(logMsg, callback){
    process.nextTick(function() {
        callback(logMsg);
    });
}

const cars = ["Ferrari", "Porsche", "Bugatti"];
let message;

for (const car of cars){
    message = "Saw a " + car;
    logCar(message, ()=>console.log("Normal Callback: " + message));
}


for (const idx in cars){
    message = "Saw a " + cars[idx];
    ((msg)=>{
        logCar(msg, ()=> console.log("Closure Callback: " + msg));
    })(message);
}
```